# TextInputLayout custom theme not working API 19

Tags: java, android, android-support-library

I am trying to use custom colors for TextInputLayout. The styles dont work as expected on API 19.

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/email_address_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    app:errorEnabled="true"
                    style="@style/textInputLayout">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                        android:id="@+id/email_address"
                        style="@style/edittextLayout"
                        android:hint="@string/email_address"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

The style for textInputLayout

```
<style name="textInputLayout" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/table_view_divider</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/content_text_dark_background</item>
        <item name="textColorError">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/content_text_dark_background</item>
        <!-- The following 2 items are needed or it'll crash when InputTextLayout.setError() is called -->
        <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorLink">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    </style>
```

This is the style for editText

```
  <style name="edittextLayout">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/content_text_dark_background</item>
    </style>
```

Base AppTheme

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/app_theme</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/app_theme_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
    </style>
```

The TextInputLayout does not seem to respect the custom theme. The colorAccent is always blue and errors are shown in red instead of white. 
The design support library used is `com.android.support:design:25.1.0`

This works perfectly fine for API 25.

I also tried to apply parent as `TextAppearance.AppCompat` to style `textInputLayout` still no luck.

Comment: Any luck? I have the same problem